# How to set timeout in mysql c++ connector

Tags: c++, mysql, macos

I am using c++ connector to connect to MySQL server. When server is offline or in sleep,the statement execute method takes a while to detect the connection problem. 

Is there a method or variable to control the waiting timeout period in client?

Regards
Devara Gudda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mysql_options` function to set the client timeout. Full details here... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html