# limit MySQL querytime using C++ code

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm using C++ programming to query  and ping MySQL server. The version of MySQL server is 5.5 and using VS2010 for C++ programming. But when the services of MySQL server is stopped, the application is taking much query execution time. Is there a way to reduce the query execution time using C++? Please direct me to sample code snippets. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254059/how-to-set-a-timeout-for-mysql-query-using-c-api - is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You should lower the timeout for the client. Take a look at this answer:
[How to set timeout in mysql c++ connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385913/how-to-set-timeout-in-mysql-c-connector)